# Ternary compared to TextStyle

Tags: flutter, conditional-operator

I rarely use ternary. And I would like some hint.

Basically I would like to display a + if the chosen color is green and a - if the chosen color is red

Here is my code

```
Text( 
 [ternary] + number[math.Random().nextInt(number.length - 1)] + "%",
 style: TextStyle(
     color: predefinedColors[math.Random().nextInt(predefinedColors.length)],
     fontSize: 10.0,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
)
```

And the list I use

```
List predefinedColors = [
  Colors.red,
  Colors.green,
];
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can include full widget?

Comment: yep of course I do that

Comment: How do you get `chosen color`, is it  just generated from random index `predefinedColors[math.Random().nextInt(predefinedColors.length)],` and It's text needed to be changed based on it?

Comment: Yep and so I'm trying to find a way to get this data and make a ternary to display + or - according to the color

Answer (score 0):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 139.0,
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 25,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      color:
                          Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                              .withOpacity(1.0),
                      child: const SizedBox(
                        width: 80,
                        height: 80,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 42),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              names[math.Random().nextInt(names.length - 1)],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 10.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              number[math.Random().nextInt(number.length - 1)] +
                                  "€",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 10.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              number[math.Random().nextInt(number.length - 1)] +
                                  "%",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: predefinedColors[math.Random()
                                      .nextInt(predefinedColors.length)],
                                  fontSize: 10.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              })),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Since you've posted an answer, I am assuming you've answered your own question and no longer need any assistance. If so, you should [edit] your answer to provide some explanation of what you've done. If that's not correct, you should edit your question to include this code, and delete your answer so that the community understands that you're still looking for a solution.